# OPA policy where if kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/reconcile: disabled label is present in helm release yaml it should display a message

Tags: open-policy-agent

is their any OPA policy example where i can design a OPA policy like if specific label is present than it should display the message or warning
i mean i want to design an OPA policy where if kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/reconcile: disabled label is present in helm release yaml it should display a message/warning that kustomize disabled label is there in helm release
can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible to return warning messages to clients from an admission webhook. The format is documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#response).

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "admission.k8s.io/v1",
  "kind": "AdmissionReview",
  "response": {
    "uid": "<value from request.uid>",
    "allowed": true,
    "warnings": [
      "duplicate envvar entries specified with name MY_ENV",
      "memory request less than 4MB specified for container mycontainer, which will not start successfully"
    ]
  }
}
```

Let's imagine you have an input object like this:

```
{
    "kind": "AdmissionReview",
    "request": {
        "kind": {
            "kind": "HelmRelease",
            "version": "v1"
        },
        "object": {
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/reconcile": "disabled"
                },
                "name": "myapp"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using a policy like this would return warnings to your client when called on the [`/v0/data` API](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/rest-api/#get-a-document-webhook)

```rb
package play

import future.keywords.contains
import future.keywords.if

warn contains msg if {
    input.request.kind == "HelmRelease"
    input.request.object.metadata.annotations["kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/reconcile"] == "disabled"
    msg := "kustomize disabled"
}

response = {
    "apiVersion": "admission.k8s.io/v1",
    "kind": "AdmissionReview",
    "response": {
        "uid": "1234",
        "allowed": true,
        "warnings": warn,
    },
}
```